# SQL Join code check and peer review

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am still fairly green when it comes to SQL joins. The below code works but I want to check that I am doing it the best way before I copy and paste errors into other work in the future.

The idea of the below code is to get the `PropertyID` and Name of a **property** from the **first Table** and using the `PropertyID` join them. In this case I am actually using every field in **Table B (thus the *)**.

So more a peer review than anything.

```
SELECT TblA.propertyid   AS PD, 
       TblA.propertyname AS PD, 
       TblB.* 
FROM   tbpropertydetails AS TblA 
       INNER JOIN tbpropertydetailssafeguarding AS TblB 
               ON TblA.propertyid = TblB.propertyid 
WHERE  TblA.regionid <> '0' 
ORDER  BY TblA.propertyid ASC
```

I am programming in VB.net but this is really standalone SQL.

Comment: You should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: ok is this work for you or not?? what is the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review and should be posted to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should be on Code Review:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, did not realize there was a codereview :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want to be caution with inner joins because you can lose potential record sets.

An example would be records in `TbPropertyDetails` that do not have an entry (no matching PropertyId) in `TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding` would vanish. There might not be a corresponding entry in the joining table because this information is entered at a later date.

Try using a `LEFT JOIN` first and then decide how you want to handle the null records i.e. those records in the primary table that had matching records in the joining table.